# How to write a function that return the value in a nested list at the index path in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

I have to write a function that return the value at index path in the list given to us.

```
def recursive_index(lst,index_path):
    if len (index_path)<1:
        return recursive_index(list(index_path),index_path[1:])
    else:
        return index_path[0]
```

The result that I should get from this function is that given:

`recursive_index([1,[2],3], [0])`,

I should get 1.
But the result I am getting is 0 and not 1 as required.

Comment: I don't understand what you want your function to actually do, but it checks the length of `index_path`, finds that `[0]` has exactly one element, goes to the `else` branch, and gets the first element of `index_path`, which is `0`. Your function does not interact with the passed `lst` in any way whatsoever.

Comment: the function is supposed to look up a value in nested list at the index path.

Comment: I'm also given that `recursive_index([1,[2],3],[])` will return the value of [1,[2],3]

Comment: do you mean by this?`return recursive_index(lst[0],lst[1:])`
I get an error saying that 'int' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function currently doesn't interact with the passed `lst` in any way. What it does now is to first check whether the passed `index_path` has more than one element. Your current test of `index_path` is `[0]`, which does not have more than one element. Your function then takes the `else` branch and returns the first element of `index_path`, which is `0`.

To fix this, make your function refer to `lst` in the appropriate places.

```
def recursive_index(lst,index_path):
    if index_path:
        return recursive_index(lst[index_path[0]],index_path[1:])
    else:
        return lst
```

If there are indices left to use, it will use the first available one to index `lst`, then pass that and the rest of the `index_path` to the function in a recursive call. When there are no more indices left, it returns whatever's left of `lst`.

Start a call with `[1, [2], 3], [0]`:

`[0]` is not empty, so take the first element of that and use it as an index. Pass along the rest of the indices.

`[1, [2], 3][0]` is `1`, which we pass. The rest of the indices is `[]`, which we pass.

`[]` is empty, so `return` the passed `lst`, which was `1`.

```
>>> recursive_index([1,[2],3], [0])
1
```

A slightly larger test:

```
>>> recursive_index([1,[2, [1]], 3], [1])
[2, [1]]
>>> recursive_index([1,[2, [1]], 3], [1,0])
2
>>> recursive_index([1,[2, [1]], 3], [1,1])
[1]
>>> recursive_index([1,[2, [1]], 3], [1,1,0])
1
```